# Converting Seconds to Years, days, hours, min, secs

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012

I have this much to convert seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds.

I need to make it work for years, and days too.

Can someone help?

```
Dim mHours As Long, mMinutes As Long, mSeconds As Long
mSeconds = 12345 ' Sample data
mHours = mSeconds \ 3600
mMinutes = (mSeconds - (mHours * 3600)) \ 60
mSeconds = mSeconds - ((mHours * 3600) + (mMinutes * 60))
MsgBox mHours & ":" & mMinutes & ":" & mSeconds
```

Comment: What is '\'? Shouldn't it be '/'?

Comment: @Maertin [I don't think so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzydt0tx).

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Why is he using the backslash? He is just trying to divide two integers and get another integer?

Comment: @Maertin If you're going to divide integers to get an integer result you want to go with an integer division. Doing a floating point division and having the interpreter cast values back and forth between Long and Double doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers I didnt know about integer division. I only knew about regular float division and hoped it automatically casts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mHours As Long, mMinutes As Long, mSeconds As Long, mDays as Long, mYears as Long
mSeconds = 12345 ' Sample data
mHours = mSeconds / 3600
mMinutes = (mSeconds - (mHours * 3600)) / 60
mSeconds = mSeconds - ((mHours * 3600) + (mMinutes * 60))
MsgBox mHours & ":" & mMinutes & ":" & mSeconds
mDays = mSeconds / 86400
mYears = mSeconds / 31557600
```

I am assuming each year has 365.25 days

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, I ended up using the Mod function.

```
If (seconds >= 31536000) Then 
                years = seconds \ 31536000 
                seconds = seconds Mod 31536000 
            End If

            If (seconds >= 86400) Then
                days = seconds \ 86400
                seconds = seconds Mod 86400
            End If
```

Thanks for all the help :)