# How to Calculate time difference in difference format in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns with dates in different format.

[image]

As you can see one column is in dd/mm/yyyy format and other is in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I want to find the time difference among the two.
Also, one column is in Date Format and other is in General Format.

I wrote a function in VB to calculate the difference like this:

```
 Function caclulateDifference(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long

   TestDates = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2)

 End Function
```

And I Call this in Excel using =caclulateDifference(b2,a2)
However,

pDate1 is coming as 10/15/19 11:38:38 AM, but pDate2 appears as 10/19/15 9:09:23 AM and then difference is coming as 0.

I want difference in day, hour and minutes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you try to recreate a function that exists?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 0 because there are 0 days between those values, PLUS, you never assign the Function a value to return anything other than the default value for `Long`.

Try it like this:

```
 Function caclulateDifference(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long

   caclulateDifference = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2)

 End Function
```

You will still get 0, but in this example, that's what you are supposed to get. Change the function to this, and then look at your debug window to see that the dates are getting formatted properly:

```
Public Function caclulateDifference(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Long

   Debug.Print pDate1
   Debug.Print pDate2

   caclulateDifference = DateDiff("d", pDate1, pDate2)

 End Function
```

Then test it using date values that are on different days to get something other than 0.

Now if you want it in more detail than days as you say, you need to return a value other than `Long` (might have milliseconds in the values too) and use a different argument in your `DateDiff` like this:

```
Public Function caclulateDifference(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Double

   caclulateDifference = DateDiff("s", pDate1, pDate2)

End Function
```

Then convert the number of seconds into the number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

[Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes, and seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667431/converting-seconds-to-years-days-hours-min-secs)

If you dont want the order to matter, and always get a positive number, use `Abs` (absolute value) function as well, like this:

```
Public Function caclulateDifference(pDate1 As Date, pDate2 As Date) As Double

   caclulateDifference = Abs(DateDiff("s", pDate1, pDate2))

End Function
```

Comment: How to get values for Hours and minutes say for the above example the value returned should be 2 Hours 29 minutes. How do I return that?

Comment: I updated the answer. Play with that a little. It requires formatting to get multiple values, which you can do inside or outside the function.

Comment: I tried your example. I am getting -8965 seconds. Thats not right correct?

Comment: Are you expecting to always get a positive number? It depends on the order in which you specify the values, or you can use `Abs` (I'll update the answer)

Comment: Input values are not dates with different formats but strings (at least the first one - as you can tell looking at pDate2 value), so the main problem is converting it to date.

Comment: The arguments to the function are dates, so VBA implicitly converts them to dates (if possible) if they are strings to begin with.

Comment: The arguments of the function are defined as dates, but the arguments passed are strings - it is obvious reading the question: `pDate2 appears as 10/19/15 9:09:23 AM`. If both cells contain dates (with different formatting) then no VBA is needed, just a simple formula like (`=B2-A2`)